# Trying Deepdict, run gensim word2vec with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, gensim, word2vec

```
from deepdist import DeepDist

from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = (SparkConf()
     .setAppName("Work2Vec")
)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
corpus = sc.textFile('AllText.txt').map(lambda s: s.split())

def gradient(model, sentences):

    syn0, syn1 = model.syn0.copy(), model.syn1.copy()   # previous weights
    model.train(sentences)
    return {'syn0': model.syn0 - syn01, 'syn1': model.syn1 - syn1}


def descent(model, update):

    model.syn0 += update['syn0']

    model.syn1 += update['syn1']


with DeepDist(Word2Vec(corpus.collect())) as dd:

    dd.train(corpus, gradient, descent)

    dd.model.save("Model")
```

Please help me, I have a 56Gb text and want to build a word2Vec model but using only gensim is very slow, so i try deepdist and their example code on the web, so I just wondering have anyone seen this kind of error

The output when i run this script:

[image: script output]

Comment: this is the link to the web http://deepdist.com/

Answer (score 0):

Note that your copied and pasted code has a typo which is corrected with this pull request: https://github.com/dirkneumann/deepdist/pull/1